# Angular UI DateTime Picker does not take manual input

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the manual input entered by the user. But it comes always NULL when I input the date as `dd/MM/yyyy`. It works when I give `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`. More over my onChange() function does not call.

Angular JS code:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * My Controller
   */
  angular.module('test').controller('MyController', MyController);
  // The $inject property is an array of service names to inject.
  MyController.$inject = ['GenericGetService', 'GenericPostService', '$routeParams', '$location', '$rootScope'];
  function MyController(GenericGetService, GenericPostService, $routeParams, $location, $rootScope) {
    var myController = this;
    myController.openCalendar = openCalendar;
    myController.isOpen = false;
    myController.onChange = onChange;
    myController.myDate = null;

    function openCalendar(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      myController.isOpen = true;
    };

    function onChange() {
      console.log(myController.myDate);
    }
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<p class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="myDate" initialPicker="date" ng-change="onChange()" class="form-control" datetime-picker="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"  defaultTime="00:00:00" data-ng-model="myController.myDate" is-open="myController.isOpen"  />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myDate.openCalendar($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
  </span>
</p>
```

Here is the code from [Demo Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/S8UqwvXNGmDcPXV7a0N3)

How do I solve this issue? How to make it work with both dd/MM/yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm format?

Note: With Javascript I can get the value as

```
var data = document.getElementById('myDate').value;
myController.myDate = new Date(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your current library already supported it
just add `alt-input-formats="['MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm', 'MM/dd/yyyy']"` in html
or you can try a live example here
https://plnkr.co/edit/QUgR6r?p=preview